# Determining Optimal Output Length for Algorithmic Pseudo-Randomness with Unique Mapping for Inputs of Size X

Tags: random-generation

I am constructing an algorithm where it should map every input to a different output and the output bits should be statistically random (that is when put into randomness test suites (like NIST), it should give a fairly good score). My question is, for a size of X for the input, how long should the output be for the above condition to hold? Is there a formula for this? If not how can I research this topic? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated!  Can you share what you have tried?  Example code is helpful.  What is lacking in the code you have tried?

Comment: @RCarnell I haven't coded yet, and the code is irrelevant, I just need a formula to find the least output length.